# Very slow query, need help optimizing

Tags: sql, query-optimization

We are using a subset of data for testing, using around 8000 records from a table of around half a million records. The query to get this subset of data was written by someone else, and is literally saying:

```
SELECT [columns]
where mastertable.master_id in (
'1',
'5',
'200',
'347',
'548'
ORDER BY master_id
```

And literally listing the 8000 ids. As soon as you start joining other tables in the query the execution time becomes ridiculously long. I assume there must be a better way of doing this? Some way of saying create a virtual mastertable_temp and then do your joins so its a much smaller subset of data?

Most of the joins are always going to be joined on master_id, but it feels like at the moment when I join other tables its doing the join for every master_id, and then looking for the specified ids?

Comment: Is master_id indexed?

Comment: do you need every single one of the half a million records, is master_id random? Is the half a million record permanent or constantly changing table. If it is permanent/static, consider slicing it into several smaller permanent tables one time. Then use those smaller tables to join in future by segmenting the master_id.

Comment: master_id is sequential, following a specific number format, however I unfortunately have no control over the 8000 records selected and a certain amount of random selection was desired, so unable to just say 'where account_id is between 1000 and 9000' if thats what you're getting at?

Comment: You're probably missing indexes, show your actual execution plan in order to get more specific answer :)